# harmon.ie and Visio 2013 license error

Tags: outlook-addin, visio, harmon.ie

I have outlook 2016 with MS Vision 2013 installed. When I try to open MS visio file from Harmon.ie, I get License error message.

Error: 
Microsoft Office cannot verify the license for this product. You should repair the office program by using control panel.

I can open the MS same MS Visio drawing manually or from sharepoint with no problem.

Answer (score 0):

This error message could not be directly related to harmon.ie. You need to reach out to Microsoft about it. You should reproduce it out of harmon.ie.
Indeed, when user clicks on a document - harmon.ie (as a client application versus web interface) determines appropriate application based on the document extension and then launches the associated desktop application by passing it the URL to the document. Running the application from command line and passing it the direct URL of the Visio document duplicates the behavior of opening the document via harmon.ie. You can get the url to your Visio document by right clicking on it from our sidebar, and select copy address.
Please check again to see if running MS Visio, from command line and providing the URL to the SharePoint document would reproduce the issue:
-Open a cmd window
-Sample command format is below
"Path_to_Visio\visio_exe.exe" "urlof_document/document.visio_extension”

----- Jean